# Running java app as root in apcupsd doshutdown causes java: Permission denied

Tags: linux, permissions, java

I'm trying to customize apcupsd doshutdown event script to run a certain java program which among other things at the end hibernates all virtual machines and finally the main system itself.

/etc/apcupsd/doshutdown is here:

```
[root@localhost apcupsd]# cat doshutdown
#!/bin/bash
#
# This shell script is placed in /etc/apcupsd
# will be called by /etc/apcupsd/apccontrol when apcupsd
# thinks to shutdown the system
# Instead of shutdown we first hibernate all VMWare VMs and the the system

wall ${USER} "Hibernate of VMs and system begins now."

rm /var/log/apcupsd_doshutdown_error.log
/usr/bin/java -version 2>> /var/log/apcupsd_doshutdown_error.log
/usr/bin/java -Dlogback.configurationFile=/etc/apcupsd/BTool.xml -cp /etc/apcupsd/BTool-assembly-1.0.jar Shutdown hibernate NOFLAG 2>> /var/log/apcupsd_doshutdown_error.log

wall ${USER} "Hibernate done."

# Do not run default shutdown after this!!!
exit 99
```

When UPS is forced to run on battery, doshutdown (or apcupsd) prints following on the wall

```
Power failure on UPS localhost.localdomain. Running on batteries.

root Hibernate of VMs and system begins now.

Battery time limit exceeded on UPS localhost.localdomain. Doing shutdown.

root Hibernate done.
```

apcupsd_doshutdown_error.log is:

```
/etc/apcupsd/doshutdown: line 11: /usr/bin/java: Permission denied
/etc/apcupsd/doshutdown: line 12: /usr/bin/java: Permission denied
```

So doshutdown script starts but it fails to run the java program.

Java permissions are:

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 22 Sep 25 11:45 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 46 Sep 25 11:45 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 9488 Jan 21 20:25 /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
```

I can run the doshutdown from terminal as ordinary user or as root but it fails when launched by apcupsd as root.

I can run java in terminal and the version is

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_71"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_71-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.71-b15, mixed mode)
```

Distro:

```
CentOS release 6.7 (Final)
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Feb 9 22:46:17 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

What is the reason for the permission error and how to fix it?

EDIT:
Added more java permissions, java version and distro. Added java -version to the doshutdown script and related error in log.

Comment: Can you run java in the terminal? It seems that /usr/bin/java is just a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/java`. Do an `ls -l /etc/alternatives/java` to check the permissions. Also, I'm not familiar with whatever linux distro you are using, but `/etc/alternatives/java` seems like an odd location for a java executable to me. Any chance something went wrong when you set up java?

Comment: It seems odd for me too but it's Centos 6.7, java is installed from standard sw repositories. I have no other problems running java in this machine or other centos boxes where the configuration is same so I don't know any problems in java setup.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm experiencing a very similar issue. It seems like even though the script is run as root there are restrictive permissions imposed on it. I just can't tell what is imposing them.